# installing magento 2 using docker, server has already docker-compose.yml, Should i write separate for magento 2 in the magento folder?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, magento, docker-compose, magento2

I have a docker-compose.yml on VPS server root

```
    version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.3.17
    command: --max_allowed_packet=256M --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated"
    ports:
       - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    restart: always
  litespeed:
    image: litespeedtech/litespeed:${LSWS_VERSION}-${PHP_VERSION}
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - ./lsws/conf:/usr/local/lsws/conf
        - ./lsws/admin/conf:/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf
        - ./bin/container:/usr/local/bin
        - ./sites:/var/www/vhosts/
        - ./acme:/root/.acme.sh/
        - ./logs:/usr/local/lsws/logs/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 443:443/udp
      - 7080:7080
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: ${TimeZone}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:5.0.2-debian-10-r72
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
environment:
    DATABASE_HOST: mysql
restart: always


elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    restart: always
volumes:
  esdata:
```

it has server configuration in above code, should i write my configuration related to magneto 2 in same file, shown below

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04
        container_name: web
        restart: always
        user: application
        environment:
          - WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=local.domain.com
          - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/pub
          - PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=EST
          - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
          - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
          - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
          - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
          - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
        volumes:
          - /path/to/magento:/app:cached
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "32823:22"
        links:
          - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - PMA_USER=root
          - PMA_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        links:
          - mysql:db
        depends_on:
          - mysql

volumes:
    db-data:
        external: false
```

if no then what should be be scenario?
1- should i create new docker-compose-magento.yml on root or inside magento folder?
2- if i write docker-compose.yml inside magento folder then how can i connect it with my server root docker folder so that i can use elasticsearch also.

Comment: For setting up a demo/new site, you might want to follow https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/docker/magento/#starting-a-demo-site. From the above file, I did not see any special config for Magento 2, only different PHP values?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know what application is running using the existing docker-compose file. And that you could check inside the existing virtual host configuration file. And that you could find inside the "sites" directory that is mapped to the lightspeed web server virtual host path that is "/var/www/vhosts" in volume mapping.

If any application is running using that docker-compose file for sure then you have to create a separate docker-compose for running Magento. In this case, a separate docker network will be created for all the Magento 2 docker-compose services and you could not access a service(ElasticSearch) on another network(on a separate docker-compose). You have to implement ES on Magento 2 docker-compose as well.

If nothing is running on the existing docker-compose then you could merge both the docker-compose files as per your requirement and understanding. Or you could apply only your new Magento 2 docker-compose file.

So the main thing here is the usage of two different networks. And docker containers can only talk to another container in the same network.

Also, lightspeed is a web server that uses the same port numbers as in the case of Apache(webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04). So there will be a port conflict if you create a new docker-compose and try to run both simultaneously. So you need to manage that as well by using different host ports. If this is a production server then that is not possible cause people are not going to access web URLs using non-default port numbers.

The solution for this is Kubernetes, where you can run multiple applications all using the same public ports but with no conflict as in Kubernetes you will divide your single physical server machine into multiple virtual machines and hence no port conflicts.

See this article for Kubernetes setup https://technicallysound.in/how-to-setup-a-static-site-on-kubernetes/

See this article for Magento setup on Docker https://technicallysound.in/how-to-setup-magento-2-on-docker-for-development/